# Question about multiple volumes on a VPS

Tags: mount

I have created a VPS at Gandi.net. It has a volume (/dev/xvda) with OS Ubuntu 22.04 on it, and a Laravel application installed in a vhost directory (~/myvhost). Laravel apps have a default storage directory for uploaded files at storage/app/public.

I would like (but I don't if that's a good idea) to decouple the Laravel application files from the storage/app/public files. So I'm wondering if I could create a new volume (/dev/xvdb), without OS, attach it to my server, and mounting it on the ~/myvhost/storage/app/public.

I did that. But when I copy files into the storage/app/public, the disk usage is taking place into the /dev/xvda volume, not in the xvdb volume. By the way the xvdb volume is not in the list when I run `df -h` :

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           390M  1.2M  389M   1% /run
/dev/xvda1       49G   23G   26G  47% /
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/xvda15     105M  6.1M   99M   6% /boot/efi
tmpfs           390M  4.0K  390M   1% /run/user/1001
```

But I can see the xvdb when running `fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/xvda: 50 GiB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 32768 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 32768 bytes / 32768 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 089874F4-B779-47D7-93FE-9363737526EB

Device       Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/xvda1  227328 104857566 104630239 49.9G Linux filesystem
/dev/xvda14   2048     10239      8192    4M BIOS boot
/dev/xvda15  10240    227327    217088  106M EFI System

Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/xvdb: 80 GiB, 85899345920 bytes, 167772160 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 32768 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 32768 bytes / 32768 bytes
```

I am a real newbie in the linux world so I am surely messing up with concepts and commands. Please help :)